# Which format is more optimal in site speed?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, litespeed

I had a site design project and at the request of my employer I designed a gif in above the fold and I report from [Gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) said that this format should be MP4! How much do you think the gif format affects the speed of the site?

Comment: Depends entirely on file size, MP4 tends to be much shorter per second than a GIF. That is the only reason they recommend this and if the GIF is really short then it probably isn't worth optimising it. It the file is over 50kb, then start looking at alternatives as a general rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0):

you better not use GIF or MP4, try to use something like Lottie json, I think it's more optimized for page speed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the Gif file download with page load and Mp4 don't, that means more size and more request to the server
for 10 second video mp4 size is smaller than Gif,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).